# How to return a new list that contains the objects in one list that are not found in another list

Tags: java

For example, list1 has "a,b,c" and list2 has "b,c,t". As a result, "a" should be returned.

Here is my code:

```
public static <E> List<I> ReturnDifference(List<E> L1, List<E> L2)
{
    List<E> L3 = new ArrayList<I>();
       Iterator<E> iter1 = L1.iterator();
       while (iter1.hasNext())
       {

           String s1 = (String)iter1.next();
           Iterator<E> iter2 = L2.iterator();

           while (iter2.hasNext())
           {
               String s2 = (String)iter2.next();

               if (s1.compareTo(s2) != 0)
               {
                   L3.add((E)s1);
               }
           }
       }
       return L3;
   }
```

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: Maybe try a for or for each loop since you arent modifying L1 or L2. Also, what are you getting when you run it? Where is the error? Please update your post with what you have tried and gotten so far

Answer (score 2):

The other answers point out that there are 3rd party libraries that will do this kind of thing.  They will do the job with less effort ... and more efficiently than your code is likely to do.

However, I'm assuming that this is a "learning exercise".  So here are some of the problems in your code.

Starting with the most basic:

1. Use the "for each" syntax:

   ```
      Iterator<T> it = x.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          T t = it.next();
          ...
      }
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
      for (T t: x.iterator() {
          ...
      }
   ```
2. Your use of typecasts is going to break if you call `ReturnDifference` with any argument that is not a list of strings.

   ```
     String s1 = (String)iter1.next();
   ```

   should be

   ```
     E s1 = iter1.next();
   ```

   and so on.
3. You don't need to use `compareTo`.  Use `equals` instead.  That has the advantage of working for element types that do not implement `Comparable<E>`.
4. Why are you returning a list whose parameter type is `I` not `E`?
5. Numerous style errors.  The most important are:

   - Method names must<sup>1</sup> start with a lowercase letter.
   - Variable names must start with a lowercase letter.

Finally, there is a glaring logic error in your code:

```
 if (s1.compareTo(s2) != 0) {
     L3.add((E)s1);
 }
```

If you look at where that statement is in the code, and think about it ... it should be apparent that you are going to add the same elements to `L3` multiple times.

I will leave it to you to figure out what to do about it.

---

<sup>1 - Technically, the compiler allows you to ignore this, but you >>can<< get yourself into trouble.  But more important, if you ask an experienced Java programmer to read code that egregiously ignores style conventions, he / she is likely to point-blank refuse.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Apache Commons Substract](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#subtract(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)) method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try intersection() and subtract() methods from [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/?org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html).

intersection() method gives you a collection containing common elements and the subtract() method gives you all the uncommon ones.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `for` loops or third-party libraries.
It's supported by the built-in [`removeAll(Collection<?> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method.

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("b","c","t");

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(list1);
result.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println(result); // prints: [a]
```

If you experience bad performance because `list2` is **large**, convert it to a `Set` first, since the `removeAll()` method is implemented by calling [`list2.contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
result.removeAll(new HashSet<>(list2));
```

That technically changes performance from *O(m⋅n)* to *O(m+n)*.